# How to post text message to server using ASIHTTPREQUEST handler in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am create one comment screen with one `textFileds` and buttons when I enter some text in `textfield` and press buttons that text should post on my sever . my request is started but my `textField` value not display . give me this message.

```
2014-10-31 14:01:29.314 SMSProject[5894:137428] request started...
2014-10-31 14:01:29.922 SMSProject[5894:137428] Response 200 : "Invalid Request"
```

I am using this **API**.

```
 -(void)sendRequest
  {
  deatilinfoarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
  @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/AddCommentForSMS"];
  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

   [request setPostValue:@"Id" forKey:@"Id"];
  [request setPostValue:commenttext forKey:@"Comment"];
  [request setPostValue:@"Author" forKey:@"Author"];
  [request setPostValue:@"SMSId" forKey:@"SMSId"];
  [request setPostValue:@"CreatedDate" forKey:@"CreatedDate"];
  [request setDelegate:self];
  [request startAsynchronous];

   }

  - (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
   {

    NSLog(@"Response %d : %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);

     //NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }

  - (void) requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request
   {
      NSLog(@"request started...");
    }

     - (void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request
     {
        NSError *error = [request error];
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
         }

     - (IBAction)btnpost:(id)sender

    {

      [self sendRequest];

        }
```

I am not getting how to code for that please suggest me.

Comment: I recommend you to use AFNetworking [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) instead of ASIHTTPRequest because that project is discontinued since 15th May 2011.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

Reference:

- [Tutorial](http://iphone-example.blogspot.in/p/asihttprequest-example.html)
- [ASIHttpRequest POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959539/asihttprequest-post)

Source:

- [code](http://iphone-example.blogspot.in/p/asihttprequest-example.html)

Comment: i want only post data not fetch

Comment: i want using asihttprequest